# How I can find a checkbox element associated with a label

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, checkbox

Im trying to create a xpath of a checkbox which has only label as unique identifier. The given Id or values change when a new checkbox element is created.

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" value="f052503c-28c2-4b2d-8bd3-0ef6cc0e563a" id="f052503c-28c2-4b2d- 
  8bd3-0ef6cc0e563a" name="ElementIds" class="i-checks" 
  checked="">
  <span class="m-l-xs"><label for="f052503c-28c2-4b2d-8bd3-0ef6cc0e563a">AuElement</label> 
  </span>
</li>
```

There are a couple of options i have tried so far but nothing is working:

```
CheckboxElement = //input[@type = 'checkbox' and @label = 'AuElement']
//input[@type='checkbox']//span[@label='AuElement']
```

For now I tried to use:
`//*[contains(text(), 'AuElement')]` xpath but i cannot use
if `CheckboxElement.Selected()` method to check if checkbox is already selected or not. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are you gonna do when you have the element on the checkbox? Click on it?

Comment: Im trying to use this element in the condition like below -
if (!CheckboxElemrnt.Enabled)
            {
                SchemeElement.Click();
            }
Right now element gets clicked without checking its pre-state i.e checked or unchecked with xpath - 
//*[contains(text(), 'AuElement')]

Comment: I think you are looking for the property `.Selected`. Something like: isChecked = e.findElement(By.tagName("input")).Selected;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```cs
"//li[.//label[text()='AuElement']]//input"
```

**Explanation:**
Find such `li` element that contains inside `label` element with `text` value of "AuElement". Now find `input` (checkbox) element inside this `li` element (it's child).
In other words:
You can use common parent element so that this parent element is found based on it's unique child `label` and then go to the `input` element inside it.